# How to wrap category labels in JfreeChart

Tags: label, jfreechart, word-wrap, categories

I have Stacked Bar Chart created using JFreeChart. The labels of the category are quite big and they overlap with the label of the next Bar. I would like to wrap it to the next line. I did some searching and found that i have to use the below code.
         setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2) in the CategoryAxis
   and still it doesn't wrap to the next line.

Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Altering the [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) [code](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) as shown and using long category names, I see the chart below. It seems to work with stacked rendering, too. Is that the desired effect?

```
private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
    ...
    // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.
    domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);
    ...
}
```

[image]