# Ranking Chart with JFreeChart

Tags: algorithm, jfreechart, bar-chart

I am looking to make a bar chart that illustrates a user's integer ranking.  The vertical axis would be the rank out of the total number of users.  I'm thinking a stacked bar chart would be the right sort of thing but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, specifically since #1 would be at the top of the bar while #last would be at the bottom.  For example, if the user was #25 out of 100, the bar would be one color for a quarter of the way up, then another representing all the other users above them.  The #1 user's bar would be all one color, and the #last user would be all the other color.

My main problem is I can't figure out the algorithm to determine the height of the bars.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: For anyone interested, I wrote a graphing routine myself to solve this.

```
package test2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rank=75;
    int totalUsers=100;
    int barWidth=400;
    int barHeight=717;
    double intervalTotal = (double)totalUsers-1.0;
    double intervalPixelSize = (double)barHeight/intervalTotal;        
    int aboveRankBarHeight=(int)Math.round(intervalPixelSize*((double)rank-1.0));
    int belowRankBarHeight=barHeight-aboveRankBarHeight;
    if (rank==1){aboveRankBarHeight=0;}
    if (rank==totalUsers){belowRankBarHeight=0;}

    //Axis and chart labels.
    String topRank = "#1";
    String myRank = "Your Rank #"+Integer.toString(rank);
    String bottomRank = "#"+Integer.toString(totalUsers);

    Color imageBackground=Color.white;
    Color axisLines=new Color(128,128,128); //Medium Gray axis lines.
    Color graphOutline=new Color(96,96,96); //Darker Gray graph outline.
    Color graphBackground=new Color(192,192,192); //Lighter Gray graph background.
    Color belowRank=new Color(85,85,255);   //Blue for bar below user rank.
    Color aboveRank=new Color(255,85,85);   //Red for bar above user rank.
    Color rankLine=Color.black;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1200, 900, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(imageBackground);    //White image background.
    g.fillRect(0,0,1200,900);       //Draw the white.
    g.setColor(axisLines);          //Medium Gray axis lines.
    g.drawLine(46, 35, 46, 788);    //Draw y-axis.
    g.drawLine(50, 792, 1189, 792); //Draw x-axis.
    g.setColor(graphOutline);       //Darker Gray graph outline.
    g.drawRect(50, 35, 1139, 753);  //Draw graph outline.
    g.setColor(graphBackground);    //Lighter Gray graph background.
    g.fillRect(51,36,1138,752);     //Draw the graph background.
    g.setColor(aboveRank);          //Red bar for above rank.
    g.fillRect(419,70,barWidth,aboveRankBarHeight);     //Draw the above rank bar.
    g.setColor(belowRank);          //Blue bar for below rank.
    g.fillRect(419,70+aboveRankBarHeight,barWidth,belowRankBarHeight);     //Draw the below rank bar.
    g.setColor(rankLine);           //Black line for rank.
    g.fillRect(419,70+aboveRankBarHeight-5,barWidth,10);    //Draw the rank line 10 pixels wide, 5 on either side of the border.
    g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 10));  //Plain 10-point default font for axis ticks.
    g.drawString(topRank, 30, 70);  //Draw top rank label.
    g.drawString(bottomRank, 15, 788);   //Draw bottom rank label.
    g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));  //Bold 20-point default font for user rank label.
    g.drawString(myRank, 250, 70+aboveRankBarHeight);   //Draw user rank label.
    g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));  //Bold 20-point default font for graph title.
    g.drawString("Rank",575,30);    //Draw graph title.
    g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));  //Bold 20-point default font for axis labels.
    g.drawString("Contributors",565,815);    //Draw x-axis label.

    //Draw vertical y-axis label.
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
    AffineTransform fontAT = new AffineTransform(); //Create a rotation transformation for the font.
    Font theFont = g2.getFont();                    //Get the current font.
    fontAT.rotate(270 * Math.PI/180);               //Derive a new font using a rotatation transform.
    Font theDerivedFont = theFont.deriveFont(fontAT);   //Apply the transform to a new font.
    g2.setFont(theDerivedFont);                     //Set the derived font in the Graphics2D context.
    g2.drawString("Number of Edits Made", 25, 488);  //Draw y-axis label.
    g2.setFont(theFont); //Put the original font back.

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("CustomImage.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your approach; a complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2782702/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Just make a dataset with a column for each user and two rows (one containing the number of users ranked higher, and the other containing the number of users ranked lower, than the user in that column).  Then you can just create a stacked bar chart, for example:

```
public class BarChartDemo2 extends JFrame {

    public BarChartDemo2(String title) {
        super(title);
        CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(100, "Users with lower rank", "Mary");
        dataset.addValue(0, "Users With higher rank", "Mary");
        dataset.addValue(70, "Users with lower rank", "John");
        dataset.addValue(30, "Users With higher rank", "John");
        dataset.addValue(0, "Users with lower rank", "Bill");
        dataset.addValue(100, "Users With higher rank", "Bill");
        return dataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("User Ranking", 
                "User", "Rank",  dataset);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(50, 240, 50));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(240, 50, 50));
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BarChartDemo2 demo = new BarChartDemo2("JFreeChart: Stack Overflow Question");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```